# PHP json_encode($array) with an image from sql-server

Tags: json

i have a sql-command for selecting all names from a sql-database running on localhost. In php i add json_encode($array) because i work with an AngularJS controller:

```
iMPULS.controller('mgCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
   $http.get("mgdb.php").then(function (response){
                $scope.mitglieder = response.data;
});
}]);
```

mgdb.php looks like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","webtech");
$mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$sql = "Select names from mitglieder"; 
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$array1 = array();
while($eintrag = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array1[] = $eintrag;   
}
echo json_encode($array1);
```

Everything works fine, through ng-repeat i got acces to the names and can display them using {{data.names}}.

As soon as i replace names with images, the whole HTML-design doesn't show up.
I can't really find out what i have to change, to make that code work with images stored in the database but names.

I guess the error must be in mgdb.php or in the controller.

Comment: So the image URLs are stored in the DB as strings, right?

Comment: Ah sorry i forget to explain this. The images itself´(jpeg files) are stored in the DB as blob.

Comment: @zerro JSON doesn't have support for blobs, try encoding it to text, for instance, with base64.

Comment: Okay, so if i got you right i quickly tested two things: 1. i changed the echo json_ecnode($array1) to echo base64_encode($array1) and 2. i tried to do $array1[] = base64_encode($eintrag) in the while-loop and echo json_encode($array1);. So my html page isnt messed up anymore but i cant display the pictures with {{data.bild}}. Or do i have to use different code than {{data.bild}} for displaying the images?

Comment: If i try to access them with <img ng-src="{{'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+data.bild}}"/>  i got a little image icon, but not my image.